# NSHTTPRESPONSE is not a subtype of @lvalue $T3

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out the problem with the code below.

Trying to send sycnronous http request to get a server response:

```
 let urlData:NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
```

What would be the change I need to make on this one?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still having issues with this one.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
var url = NSURL.URLWithString("http://www.google.com")
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
var response : NSURLResponse? = NSURLResponse(URL: url, MIMEType:"text/html", expectedContentLength: -1, textEncodingName: nil) as NSURLResponse?
var error : NSError? = NSError()
if let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error) {
    println(data)
}
```

If I were to guess, your `NSURLResponse` and `NSError` were not optional.